# 変数と文字列を組み合わせた変数を変数で使いたい

Tags: javascript

#### 目的

変数と文字列を組み合わせた変数を変数で使いたい
説明が下手ですいません。

例えばこのようなスクリプトを実行した際に、一番したの処理だけエラーを吐きます。

```
var Over = "Overrrrr"
var Page = "Stack" + Over + "Flow"

JSON.parse(httpObj.response).Ids.find((v) => v.User == "Overrrrr");
JSON.parse(httpObj.response).Ids.find((v) => v.User == Over);

JSON.parse(httpObj.response).Ids.find((v) => v.User == Over).StackOverrrrrFlow;
JSON.parse(httpObj.response).Ids.find((v) => v.User == Over).Page;
```

`.StackOverrrrrFlow`を文字列と組みあせた`.Page`で実行しようとしているのが原因だとは思うのですが、どのように改善すれば動くようになるのでしょうか？

#### 追記

実際に表示される内容を追記しました。お手数かけてすいません。

```
JSON.parse(httpObj.response).Ids.find((v) => v.User == "Overrrrr");
// Object { User: Overrrrr, Id: "82955", StackOverrrrrFlow: "DOTCOM" }

JSON.parse(httpObj.response).Ids.find((v) => v.User == Over);
// Object { User: Overrrrr, Id: "82955", StackOverrrrrFlow: "DOTCOM" }

JSON.parse(httpObj.response).Ids.find((v) => v.User == Over).StackOverrrrrFlow;
// "DOTCOM"

JSON.parse(httpObj.response).Ids.find((v) => v.User == Over).Page;
// undefined
```

`"DOTCOM"`を取得させたいです。

Comment: JSON.parse(httpObj.response).Ids には具体的に何が入っていて、find((v) => v.User == Over).Page でどういう結果になって欲しくて、実際はどういうエラーを吐くのでしょうか? 
後半のコードは eval(t2) するしかないですが、前半の問題とは関係なさそうな予感がします。

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。追記いたしました。また後半部分は関係ないみたいなので削除しました。申し訳ございませんでした。また、別の方に回答いただいた方法で解決致しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

もちょっと具体的な入力と出力を書いて欲しいですが、当てずっぽうで回答すると、

```js
JSON.parse(httpObj.response).Ids.find((v) => v.User == Over)[Page];
```

ではないでしょうか。

文字列を変数名としてアクセスするには`eval()`が必要ですが、文字列をプロパティ名とするには`[]`でアクセスすればよいです。

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。当方の説明不足でお手数をかけてしまい申し訳ありませんでした。ご教授いただいた方法で試した結果無事に望む結果を得られました。